# Rewrite AngularJS URL

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can an AngularJS site's url be automatically rewritten from `example.com/app` to `example.com/app/#/`?

Currently, it changes from `example.com/app` to `example.com/app#/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ /$1/#/ [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. AngularJS does add a `#` to the URLS to allow to browser to handle further links.  Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: If you enter `example.com/app` what does it become?

Comment: It becomes `example.com/app#/`

Comment: Open `example.com/app` in Chrome dev tool to see what does it get redirected to? Make sure there is one rule as shown above.

Comment: It does work when I have only one redirect rule.  However, then I get a 404 error.  Thanks for your help.  I'm going to play around with this for a while.

Comment: Ok in that case I think there are other conflicting rules. Better you keep this just below `RewriteEngine On`