# Why my angularjs URL route is different?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My query is exactly the same as [Rewrite AngularJS URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476598/rewrite-angularjs-url) , but I am using IIS as my web server.

How do I fix the URL? Currently my URL looks like

```
http://example.com/app#/
```

which needs to be changed like

```
http://example.com/app/#/
```

Answer (score 0):

In case we are using ASP.NET MVC runtime to trigger `Index` action on the `HomeController` to act as "index.html" (returning the view `index.cshtml`) - we can just add these lines into it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var root = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
    var applicationPath = Request.ApplicationPath;
    var path = Request.Path;

    var hasTraillingSlash = 
          root.Equals(applicationPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
       || !applicationPath.Equals(path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    if (!hasTraillingSlash)
    {
        return Redirect(root + "#");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Check this [Browser address will not be displayed correctly in ui-route](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24987100/1679310)